# Getting files from the filebrowser

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-browser

I am using filebrowser to upload some files

I have a dropdownlist that I want to populate with values/titles of the files that are already on the file browser. But I have no idea how to get these values. Below I added the code about how the a zip file/values are uploaded to the filebrowser

```
protected void DeployButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var projectPath = Server.MapPath(Project.DataDirectoryPath);
        var zipToUnpack = String.Format("{0}/FileBrowser/FOLDERNAME/filer/{1}.zip", projectPath, "ap");
        var unpackDirectory = projectPath;
        using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
        {
            // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
            // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip1)
            {
                entry.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        } 
    }
```

So on the filebrowser as an example, there is a file called meeting.zip. I want to put "meetings" in the dropdownbox, when a user wants to chose a file. But I have no idea where to start. I also don't know what to search for, to find the solution. Any ideas?

I apologize if the description or question is vague, please let me know if you need it explained differently

Comment: What is a "filebrowser"?

Comment: how about stepping thru the code and where you declare zipToUnpack tell us what the value is.. can you print out the full file path and or string ? I have a feeling that you may have your String.Format Params reading incorrectly or you are getting double file paths in the projectPath vaiable